# Node.js Decompress base64 encoded zipped string with gzip

Tags: node.js, base64, compression, gzip

First time posting on here, so sorry if I'm missing anything. I'm trying to decode this base64 string in Node.js like so:

```
encoded_string = H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQAoxwpHAwAAAA=
decoded_string = Buffer.from(encoded_string, 'base64').toString('binary')
```

My goal is for *decoded_string* to evaluate to "Hello world!", but I need to use the gzip algorithm to output the correct value. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [this function](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gunzipsync_buffer_options) to decode the binary.

Usage Example:

`zlib.gunzipSync(Buffer.from(encoded_string, 'base64')).toString('utf8');`